# Lavazza Amodo Mio - steams

Tags: coffee-machines, cleaning

When I try to make a cup of coffee my Lavazza machine steams and splutters all over the place/through the water vent (not the milk frother). I have tried cleaning it. What else can I do?

Comment: So steam is coming out of your group head?